# Algorithmic Upper Bound for my solution

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I'm working on some homework and I want to make sure my analysis of the upper bound for the solution is correct.

Here's what I do.

1. I read n characters from an input string. // O(n)
2. Construct a min heap of size k(where k is a large constant). // O(n)
3. Retreive the k entries from the min heap. // O(k *log n).

The complexity of my solution is therefore O(n+ k·logn). I was wondering whether I can safely approximate to O(n), if I take into consideration that k is a constant.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Is there any missing detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if k is a constant, then Θ(n + k log n) = Θ(n) + Θ(k log n) = Θ(n) + Θ(log n) = Θ(n).

Comment: Doesn't _`k` is a large constant_ comment mean that `(log n)` dominates?

Comment: @user58697 "Large" constant here is not a mathematically relevant distinction, though you're right that in practice one has to be careful with abusing big-O notation that way.